# Headless install via WiFi ala IoT

Tags: wifi, headless

I have searched for a solution that is often used in configuring of IoT devices.

The flow is like this:

1. The Raspberry Pi starts
2. Is there a WiFi config ? If yes, boot with the WiFi credentials
3. There is no WiFi credentials, start a AP with as a captive portal.
4. Connect a device to the AP and configure the WiFi network SSID/Password that you would like to connect to via a web interface.
5. Raspberry Pi reboots.

Is there a Raspberry Pi image that works like this ?